# set style based on property with function, efficiency

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have a few icons, these icons describes what state my object is in, if it's open, closed, declined etc.. If the object is 'open' then my icon for 'open' should have `opacity 1`, the rest should have `opacity 0.4`. To achieve this I have a function like this:

```
$scope.setOpacity = function(status, icon){
    console.log(status,icon);
    if (status == icon){
        return 1;
    }else {
        return 0.4;
    }
};
```

and it is called from the view like this:

```
ng-style="{'opacity': setOpacity(editable.Status,'open')}"
```

When I open an object, using a `$modal` window, my `console.log(status,icon);` runs three times, and then once everytime I click anywhere on the view. As I understand this is normal, it updates the view (so if the value of status were to change, so would the opacity of the icon)

Is this an efficient way of doing this, and if not, could it be done another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create two css classes like

```
.opacity-1 {
      opacity: 1;
 }
```

and

```
.opacity-0.4{
    opacity: 0.4;
 }
```

and then conditionally apply this class

```
<span ng-class="{'opacity-1': status == icon,
                 'opacity-0.4': status !== icon}">some icon</span>
```

Even you can add more classes like this on different conditions